# vba excel function find all unique values and put in one

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I have code that find all values, sorts then put it one cell, but i have no idea how to remove duplicates.

```
Public Function ALookUps(ByVal myVal, Rng As Range, ByVal ref As Long) As String
Dim a, i As Long
a = Rng.Value
With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
        If a(i, 1) = myVal Then .Add a(i, ref) 'the linie i tried change
    Next
    If .Count > 0 Then .Sort: ALookUps = Join(.ToArray, vbCrLf)
End With
End Function
```

I did tray to add another condition, but it gave me error :

```
If (a(i, 1) = myVal And (a(i, ref) <> a(i - 1, ref))) Then .Add a(i, ref)
```

could you tell me what i did wrong and how to fix it?

What I'm trying to do:
I have a table with multiple values, and different parameter(already a pivot) and i need to connect them based on key world in another table.
So i try to do

Look up in table for input value (a) create  array/list of unique values and put this to one cell with specific separator.

I fonud other function, i put in another column. Can this be combined in one function?

```
Public Function UniqueParts(separator As String, toParse As String) As String
Dim d As New Scripting.Dictionary, part As Variant, i As Integer
For Each part In Split(toParse, separator)
    d(part) = 1
Next
UniqueParts = Join(d.Keys, separator)
End Function
```

i

Comment: I think a screenshot of the data set and giving a clearer view of what you're inputting into your UDF variables and what you're expecting to output would be helpful.

Comment: This looks more like a helper function than  udf to return a unique list. Clarify your situation with sample data together with expected results. [mcve]

Comment: i added some clarification, if you have better solution don't hesitate to post easier one (i'm vba noob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if it `Contains` the value.

I don't know what your arguments do so I created a sample function instead. 
Obviously this will need updating to suit your needs.

```
Sub Test1()

    Debug.Print ALookUps

End Sub

Public Function ALookUps() As String

    Dim rng As Range, rCell As Range

    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")

    With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        For Each rCell In rng
            If Not .contains(rCell.Value) Then
                .Add rCell.Value
            End If
        Next rCell

        If .Count > 0 Then
            .Sort
            ALookUps = Join(.toarray, vbCrLf)
        End If
    End With

End Function
```